How many follow-up emails should I send to professors to inquire about working in their laboratory as a master's student?
I plan to pursue my master’s in Korea next semester, and it’s highly recommended to secure a professor before applying to the university. I reached out to a total of 7 Korean professors via email. Since I’m proficient in Korean (C1/TOPIK 5), I wrote the emails in Korean and had a native friend review them to ensure there were no errors, I included the English translation at the bottom of the email just to be sure. Each email was personalized after thoroughly reading the professors’ papers, where I expressed my genuine interest in their work and briefly introduced my research background. I also attached my CV, undergraduate thesis, and a brief summary of my research experience. However, only one professor has responded so far. I sent follow-up emails to the remaining six professors four days ago, but I have yet to receive any replies.
I also emailed the lab manager of one of the professors who did not respond, but I haven't received a reply from him either. The department I am considering applying to is Chemical and Biomolecular Engineering.
How many follow-up emails can I send to professors to inquire about working in their laboratory as a master's student?

None is the correct number!

Do you understand the application system in South Korea? Does one normally apply to a professor or, as in the US, to the department? If the latter, few such letters get answered. If the former, people normally advertise positions.

There are many students who reach out to professors to study in Korea before applying to university. I also researched several international students who are pursuing their master's degrees, and they recommended the same approach, as they followed this exact strategy.

안녕하세요! Since you've mastered Korean (congratulations!), I'd recommend asking your question in a Korean-language forum (if you can find one). Academia differs greatly from place to place, and the best advice will come from people familiar with the local culture and application procedures. Good luck to you!

You CAN send as many emails as you like, the question here is rather how many emails SHOULD you send. I have edited your title accordingly.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/94395/waiting-to-hear-back-from-a-professor-how-long-should-i-wait also duplicate

@Sursula It seems my situation is quite different from theirs. Nonetheless, thank you for your reply

As a professor, I always find baffling when students write me such mails with their CV, thesis, etc., etc., but never mention their source of funding. Just like it is not mentioned here. However, very often this is the primary question I have to clarify before reading everything else.

@rg_software My funding is self-supported, and I am not requesting any financial assistance. In my previous email, I mentioned that I am applying to their department through the university. My only aim is to contribute to the research in their laboratory. Nothing in the e-mail sent was baffling.

Voting to leave open - I don't think it's a dupe as it is about Korea, and answers may be different from those applicable elsewhere. However, I don't know how likely you are to get a good answer here, as I don't know how many here are familiar with the Korean system. As somebody else said, it might be worth your while finding a community of Korean academics to ask.

One follow-up e-mail is the maximum. You only send the follow-up e-mail if you e-mailed one or at most two group leaders and that's exactly that group where you want to work. If your e-mail wasn't replied, in 90% of the cases that was deliberate and maybe just in 10% of cases your e-mail got lost in professor's spam folder. I am now talking about a situation when you are just writing an unsolicited e-mail to someone in hope they would have an open position and not when you apply to an announced vacancy that has been officially advertised, usually with a fixed deadline. In the latter case you should get a confirmation letter that your application has been received. If you didn't, sending a reminder is always appropriate.

I see, thank you for taking the time to answer. Some professors have stated on their lab websites that they have open positions for master's students and that they would like to be contacted directly via email. Since ı got no reply even though ı sent and follow-up email,  I guess ı should give up.

@beesarecute One possibility is that the professors are busy with something else at the moment, and plan to read all the emails from prospective applicants at the same time later.

Often this statement professors have on the web site was written years ago when they became professors. They want you to apply but  in case there are too many applications, they cannot reply to everyone. The absence of a reply means they don't have anything to offer you at the moment.
